# HowTo: Enable IntelliSense for MVC Razor in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense, orchardcms

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web some time in early 2012, then I performed an update in mid 2013. Next, I started using the Orchard Content Management System. The problem is that IntelliSense is not working. When I open .cshtml files, I get no IntelliSense for inline server side code such as @Html. How do I get Razor IntelliSense working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2012 Express for Web is what worked for me.

1. Use Control Panel > Programs & Features to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.
2. Go to [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-web) to download and reinstall the most recent version.